# Net core generic repository pattern how to inject DbContext without knowing its type at compile time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, asp.net-core

I'm working on a web api project decoupled and the bussiness logic its decoupled in extensions (separated projects, that gives me a lot of shared code between projects), thats why I'm working on a data layer also decoupled, everything its working but the only thing that keeps me everything coupled its AppDbContext.cs

Here is a POC code so you can get my idea (my problem):

**AppDbContext.cs**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

**IEntity.cs**

```
public interface IEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

**IRepository.cs**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
}
```

**GenericRepository.cs**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
{
    private readonly AppDbContext dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
}
```

and register it in the composition root like this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));
```

As you can see, my generic repository uses AppDbContext, but what if in a different project that is called different ? or inherits from IdentityContext, how can I make my Generic Repository, DbContext independient but also configurable at startup ?

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that, in some cases there will be more than one DbContext implementation.

Comment: if it's not code specific to `AppDbContext` (the current code is not), you can inject the base class `DbContext` instead

Comment: @Jonesopolis what if you have more than one DbContext implementation configured ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lowest common factor here is `DbContext`.

Rafactor `GenericRepository` to explicitly depend on `DbContext`

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey> {
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext) {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll() {
        return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
}
```

At composition root you would then make the association

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:connectionString"]));

services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));   
services.AddScoped<DbContext, AppDbContext>();
```

---

### Update

In case of multiple Contexts, That would require a little more abstraction. In cases like that I create a specific abstraction for each context. like `IDbContext` or `ILoggingContext`

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable {
    int SaveContext();
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>();
    //...other relevant EF members, etc
}

public interface IAppDbContext : IDbContext {

}

public interface ILogDbContext : IDbContext {

}
```

and have my `DbContext` derived classes inherit from  the one relevant to it.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IAppDbContext {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions) {
    }
}

public class LogDbContext : DbContext, ILogDbContext {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<LogDbContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions) {
    }
}
```

From there the generic repository would explicitly depend on the relevant abstraction(s)

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey> {
    private readonly IDbContext dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(IAppDbContext dbContext) {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

and then do the necessary configuration at composition root.

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:appConnectionString"]));

services.AddDbContext<LogDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:logConnectionString"]));

services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));   
services.AddScoped<IAppDbContext, AppDbContext>();
services.AddScoped<ILogDbContext, LogDbContext>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, what if you have configured more than one DbContext on the same webapi, for loggin propouses and stuff like that ....

Comment: @DavidNoreña, That would require a little more abstraction. In cases like that I create a specific abstraction for each context. like `IDbContext` and `ILoggingContext` and have my `DbContext` derived classes inherit from  the one relevant to it.

Comment: I know is a lot to ask but, could you please give me an example using TWO DbContexts ?

Comment: @Nkosi I know this was answered way back but is there any other way on implementing multiple DbContexts? I got the same issue with the OP and resolved with your answer but I'm just curious for other solutions.

Comment: @Nkosi Here the generic repository make only use of the `IAppDbContext`, what if I want to use `ILogDbContext` without knowing the type on runtime?

Comment: @Nkosi but DbSet is not generic so doing IDbContext  wouldn't help if you say wanted to create a repo which was reusable between EF6 and EFcore. Is there away to make a generic Repo.... which both EF6 and Core would be able to interface off.. it doesn't seem like it as all BaseRepos, have a DbContext... which would then need to be abstracted Like IDbContext , but then DbSet ... is specific to lib, could you assit.

Comment: @Seabizkit at the time of this answer there was a generic `DbSet<T>`

Comment: @Nkosi ....mmm i need `IDbSet<T>` aka an interface for it... but wouldn't know how to hook up, aka if its just `DbSet<T>` inside the IDbContext  Interface aka not an interface then the implementation come from some where, your forced at this point to make it coupled.. to Either EF6 or EFCore

Comment: @Seabizkit fair point. I'll have to give it some thought

Comment: The design would definitely need to change now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler solution (but not cleaner). For the notice I'm actually against using Repository pattern for EF.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<context1>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Connection1), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
services.AddDbContext<context2>(options => options.UseSqlServer(DbConnection2), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

// Build an intermediate service provider
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

services
    .AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Repository.Models.SubmissionEntry>>(_ => new GenericRepository<SomeSpecificModelThatUsesContext2>(sp.GetService<context2>(), true))
    .AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>))
```

GenericRepository.cs

```
just add second constructor         

private readonly DbContext dbContext;

public GenericRepository(context1 ctx)
{dbContext=ctx}
public GenericRepository(context2 ctx, bool fakeParamToAddSecondConstructor) 
{dbContext=ctx}
```